# How to play live stream in iOS devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, http-live-streaming

I am trying to develop an app for iOS that plays live streaming of a TV channel. Please guide me how I can play that.

I want to know options available for this.

Thanks,
Cp

Comment: Use `MPMoviePlayer` to achieve this simply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official apple documentation is always a nice place to start. It has lot of info and code samples to help you get started. The option you should consider using is HTTP streaming.

https://developer.apple.com/streaming/